# convert a single into 8 bytes invb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, byte

I have a single that might have a decimal place but might not.
I have to put the digit before the decimal into the first 4 bytes and the digit after in the next 4 bytes.
So 1.1 would be 01-00-00-00-01-00-00-00
or 2.1 would be 02-00-00-00-01-00-00-00
or 1 would be 01-00-00-00-00-00-00-00

The digit before the decimal point is stored like an integer in bytes the same with the digit after the point.
So 1.1 gets split into 1 and 1 and then stored as 2 DWORDS: 01000000 and 01000000

Comment: This makes no sense.  Do you mean, say, 00-00-00-02-01-00-00-00 for 2.1?

Comment: I forgot sorry, It's only 1 digit either side of the point. So there can't be 10.01

Comment: No I didn't, let me say it another way.

Comment: Woof, that makes little sense.  Convert it to a string first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Dim b(7) As Byte
b(0) = Convert.ToByte(Math.Floor(n))
b(4) = Convert.ToByte((n - Math.Floor(n)) * 10)
```